# Python: Iterating List of Dates and Selecting First Day of Fiscal Week

Tags: python, list, loops, pandas

I have a list of dates and fiscal weeks in Python. I am using the following code to pull them in from a CSV and load into a list:

```
import csv

with open('Fiscal3.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader2 = list(reader)
```

Here is what the list looks like:

```
for a, b in reader2:
print a,b
```

Result:

```
1/13/2020 50
1/14/2020 50
1/15/2020 50
1/16/2020 50
1/17/2020 50
1/18/2020 50
1/19/2020 50
1/20/2020 51
1/21/2020 51
1/22/2020 51
1/23/2020 51
1/24/2020 51
1/25/2020 51
1/26/2020 51
```

What code can I use to get the first day of the week and then print it for each day in the week, like the following output below?

Output I am looking to get:

```
[each day]   [first day of week]

1/13/2020 50 1/13/2020
1/14/2020 50 1/13/2020
1/15/2020 50 1/13/2020
1/16/2020 50 1/13/2020
1/17/2020 50 1/13/2020
1/18/2020 50 1/13/2020
1/19/2020 50 1/13/2020
1/20/2020 51 1/20/2020
1/21/2020 51 1/20/2020
1/22/2020 51 1/20/2020
1/23/2020 51 1/20/2020
1/24/2020 51 1/20/2020
1/25/2020 51 1/20/2020
1/26/2020 51 1/20/2020
```

Comment: Could you add in the code you've written so far?

Comment: And include python code with an example of your data frame that we can run ourselves. Your example and formatting is most unclear.

Comment: Included a better description of the problem- looking to simply add the first day of the week to each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


res=[]
dates=[('1/13/2020', 50),('1/13/2020', 49),('1/13/2020', 52)]
for a, b in dates :
    dt = datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y')
    start = dt - timedelta(days=dt.weekday())
    end = start + timedelta(days=6)
    res.append((a,b, str(start)[:10]))


print res
```

Input :

`dates=[('1/13/2020', 50),('1/13/2020', 49),('1/13/2020', 52)]`

Output:

```
[('1/13/2020', 50, '2020-01-13'), ('1/13/2020', 49, '2020-01-13'), ('1/13/2020', 52, '2020-01-13')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the best solution you can get but.
Here I'm assuming that your first line will always be your first fiscal day

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, MINYEAR
```

with open ('Fiscal3.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    first_day = datetime(1, 1,MINYEAR)
    for i in r:
        date_value = [ int(x) for x in i[0].split(' ')[0].split('/') ]
        value_as_datetime = datetime(date_value[2], date_value[0], date_value[1])

# if the difference is greater than a week, we want to update our first_day value
    if value_as_datetime - first_day >= timedelta(weeks=1):
        first_day = value_as_datetime
    print value_as_datetime, first_day

Results:

> 2020-01-13 00:00:00 2020-01-13 00:00:00
> 2020-01-14 00:00:00 2020-01-13 00:00:00
> 2020-01-15 00:00:00 2020-01-13 00:00:00
> 2020-01-16 00:00:00 2020-01-13 00:00:00
> 2020-01-17 00:00:00 2020-01-13 00:00:00
> 2020-01-18 00:00:00 2020-01-13 00:00:00
> 2020-01-19 00:00:00 2020-01-13 00:00:00
> 2020-01-20 00:00:00 2020-01-20 00:00:00
> 2020-01-21 00:00:00 2020-01-20 00:00:00
> 2020-01-22 00:00:00 2020-01-20 00:00:00
> 2020-01-23 00:00:00 2020-01-20 00:00:00
> 2020-01-24 00:00:00 2020-01-20 00:00:00
> 2020-01-25 00:00:00 2020-01-20 00:00:00
> 2020-01-26 00:00:00 2020-01-20 00:00:00

You should also take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html